# $n^{th}$ derivative of $\cot x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\cot(x)$?

I tried to differentiate it may times:

[image]

I can't see a pattern forming. Please help.

Comment: Well, there is certainly a pattern -- you're getting a polynomial in cot(x) which is alternatingly even/odd and whose degree is the order of the differential operator + 1. So, assuming this fact, you can write down explicit recursive formulas for the coefficients.

Comment: What kind of answer are you seeking? Closed form? Recursive? Summation? Other?

Comment: The coefficients of these polynomials, up to minus or plus sign, are given in
[OEIS](https://oeis.org/A008293), Triangle of coefficients in expansion of D^n (tan x) in powers of tan x.

Answer (score 10):

There is a pattern but it is not simple. Apparently the pattern was found only quite recently:

> V.S. Adamchik, [On the Hurwitz function for rational arguments](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2006.08.096), *Applied Mathematics and Computation*, Volume 187, Issue 1, 1 April 2007, Pages 3–12

See Lemma 2.1. The text is available at the author's site: [pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/AMC.pdf)

There is also a recursion formula:

> If $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \cot x = (-1)^n P_n(\cot x)$, then $P_0(u)=u$, $P_1(u)=u^2+1$, and
>   $$
> P_{n+1}(u) = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} P_j(u) P_{n-j}(u)
> $$ for $n\ge 1$.

This formula appears in

> Michael E. Hoffman, [Derivative polynomials for tangent and secant](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2974853), 
>   *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 102, No. 1 (Jan., 1995), pp. 23-30

I learned of this formula and paper in

> Kurt Siegfried Kölbig, [The polygamma function and the derivatives of the cotangent function for rational arguments](https://cds.cern.ch/record/298844), CERN-CN-96-005, 1996.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cot x=\frac1\pi \psi \left(1-\frac{x}{\pi }\right)-\frac1\pi\psi \left(\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$ (where $\psi$ is [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function)), its n-th derivative [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28-1%20-%20n%29%20PolyGamma%5Bn%2C%20x%2F%5C%5BPi%5D%5D%20%2B%20%28-1%29%5En%20%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28-1%20-%20n%29%20%20%20%20PolyGamma%5Bn%2C%201%20-%20x%2F%5C%5BPi%5D%5D)

$\cot^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n \pi ^{-n-1} \psi ^{(n)}\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi }\right)-\pi ^{-n-1} \psi ^{(n)}\left(\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$

Wolfram Mathematica says [you can express it in cotangent functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/02/0003/):

$\cot^{(n)}(x)=(-2 i)^n (\cot (x)+i) \underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k (i \cot (x)+1)^k k! \mathcal{S}_n^{(k)}$, where $S$ are gives the Stirling number of the second kind.

There are also [other formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/20/03/).