# Is it possible to find $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{1}{e^{ax}+b}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> Is it possible to find $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac{1}{e^{ax}+b}$ ?

I am introduced to $n^{th}$ differentiation and leibniz theorem as a first year undergraduate.
But what i observe is there are some explicit formula for the  $n^{th}$ derivative of $\sin x$,$\cos x$,$\log(ax+b)$,$\frac{1}{ax+b}$, etc but why there isn't any method given for $\sec x$, $\csc x$ etc.

---

If the highlighted question can be answered then it is possible to find the $n^{th}$ derivative of secx.
How ?
$$y=\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac{2 e^{ix}}{e^{2ix}+1}$$
Now one can use lebniz theorem of $n^{th}$ differentiation to find the n derivative of product of two functions whose general derivative is known. Now here $e^{ix}$ whose derivative can be found easily. The latter part $\frac{1}{e^{2ix+1}}$ is not known.

Comment: If $y=\frac{1}{e^{ax}+b}$, then $y'= a  b y^2 - a  y$. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: How good is that , differentiation of $n$ times of this will yield its n-th derivative in terms of n-1th or less.

Comment: For $\cot x$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701540/nth-derivative-of-cot-x

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = \frac{a^n P_n(e^{ax})}{(e^{ax}+b)^{n+1}}$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree  $n$, with
$P_0(t) = 1$ and 
$$ P_{n+1}(t) = t (b + t) P_n'(t) - (n+1) t P(t)$$
I don't think there's a "closed form", unless you count [Faà_di_Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Comment: (+1)Thanks sir, can you recommend any references where i can find the proof of Faa di bruno's formula. I have never heard of this before.